# Page is in sitemap but google says "No referring sitemaps detected"

Tags: sitemap, google-index, crawl-errors

On this website that I'm managing, there is an inexplicable error that is effecting SERPs and rankings.
Specifically, this page `/botox-nyc/` is showing as indexed in GSC

However, when expanding the view the specific URL is not in the sitemap
[image]

When going to sitemaps - everything is showing as fully processed & active:
[image]

And the page is in the sitemap as below:
[image]

This has caused dramatic drop in rankings & it's not clear how to deal with this issue.
Thank you in advance for helping!